# JavaScript/jQuery callbacks of functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have 2 functions.

```
function f1() {
    $.ajax(..., success: function(response) {
        // some code executed whenever request is completed.
    }
}

function f2() {
    // my code
}
```

I need to call these functions one after another.

```
f1() // waiting until ajax request in the function is complete.
f2()
```

I tried `$.when().then()`, however it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$.ajax` call returns an instance of `$.Deferred` which is used to track the progress of the call - that is what you need to return from your `f1` function.  You can then use `.then()`, `.done()` etc.

**Edit in response to comments**

If you want to invoke a callback within `f1` as well as externally you can return the result of the `.pipe` method.

```
function f1() {
    return $.ajax(/*...*/).pipe(function() {
        //local 'done' handler
    });
}

function f2(resultFromF1Handler) {
    //...
}

f1().done(f2);
```

Comment: That work's, however, f2 is still executed a little bit too early. I need to call f2 after ajax request and its callback in f1 is executed.

Comment: @Hvandracas see my edit - updated example with callback in `f1`

Answer (score 1):

```
function f1(onsuccess) 
{
    $.ajax(
    { 
        success: function(r) 
        { 
            // some code
            onsuccess(r);
        }
    });
}

function f2() 
{
    // my code
}

f1(f2);
```

Comment: This works, but is not as flexible as using `$.Deferred`: what if you want to attach 2 'success' handlers?  Or a 'fail' handler?

Comment: @Steve, true but workable... `function success(){ f2(); f3();}    f1(success, fail);`

Comment: +1 If you don't already know how to use deferreds, this is the most straightforward way to call `f2()` from `f1()` without `f1` knowing any specifics of `f2`.  All it's doing is designing f1() to support calling an arbitrary function after its ajax call succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest calling f2() inside the anonymous function that is executed as f1()'s success.

Is there a problem with doing that?

Comment: But that would mean that `f1` needs to be aware of `f2`.  By using the `$.Deferred`, these two functions could be in separate files or separate libraries and still work as the OP desires